# Manually editing XML code

Tags: c#, xml

I'am extremely new when it comes to creating and using XML files.

Say for example I have this code for storing highscores

```
    [Serializable]
    public class HighScoreData
    {
        public string[] PlayerName;
        public int[] Score;
        public int[] Level;
    }
```

and I want to create xml code to that when it deserializes it'll look something like this

playername= {"Rocco","Shawn","Derrick"}

score= {100,200,300}

level = {1,2,3}

What would that xml code look like?

Comment: That output isn't in XML format yet the question title has XML in the name. Did you want this to be the content of an XML tag? Or something else?

Comment: What you want looks more like JSON than XML.. Anyway, you can use methods of XmlSerializer class for this.

Comment: I already had the code to deserialize it.

I just want to know what the xml file should look like.

For example I have an xml file called HighScores.xml

how should that file be formatted?

@ago yeah something like that. basically I'm just want to manual write the XML code so that i can create something like this HighScoreData scores= new HighScoreData();

and when I look at scores.playername[0] i get "Rocco"

Comment: If you're looking for a custom format, you can implmenet `ISerializable`.

Answer (score 4):

Why did you model it like that? In my opinion the following example is more compelling.

```
[Serializable]
public class HighScoreData
{
    public string PlayerName;
    public int Score;
    public int Level;
}

[Serializable]
public class HighScoresCollection
{
    List<HighScoreData> HighScores; 
}
```

Then, when you serialize the highScore, you get something like this:

```
<HighScoresCollection>
    <HighScoreData>
        <PlayerName>Rocco</PlayerName>
        <Score>100</Score>
        <Level>1</Level>
    </HighScoreData>
    <HighScoreData>
        <PlayerName>Shawn</PlayerName>
        <Score>200</Score>
        <Level>2</Level>
    </HighScoreData>
    <HighScoreData>
        <PlayerName>Derrick</PlayerName>
        <Score>300</Score>
        <Level>3</Level>
    </HighScoreData>
</HighScoresCollection>
```

Well, the need for the `HighScoresCollection` class in my example is arguable, and you can just have a list of scores, IMO.

Comment: The `HighScoresCollection` or any other single root element allows for  dumping the xml into a standalone file and may also serve as a hook for namespace declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to have single object with multiple members (Arrays). I think you need an Array of objects.
Anyway for your sample it is:

```
<HighScoreData>
    <ArrayOfPlayerName>
        <PlayerName>Rocco</PlayerName>
        <PlayerName>Shawn</PlayerName>
        <PlayerName>Derrick</PlayerName>
    </ArrayOfPlayerName>
    <ArrayOfScore>
        <Score>100</Score>
        <Score>200</Score>
        <Score>300</Score>
    </ArrayOfScore>
    <ArrayOfLevel>
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Level>3</Level>
    </ArrayOfLevel>
</HighScoreData>
```

For array of objects XML whould be lke this:

```
<HighScoreData>
    <Player>
        <PlayerName>Rocco</PlayerName>
        <Score>100</Score>
        <Level>1</Level>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <PlayerName>Shawn</PlayerName>
        <Score>200</Score>
        <Level>2</Level>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <PlayerName>Derrick</PlayerName>
        <Score>300</Score>
        <Level>3</Level>
    </Player>
</HighScoreData>
```

Answer (score -1):

As follows:

```
   <xml>
   <HighScoreData>
      <PlanerName>Player 1</PlayerName>
      <Score>200</Score>
      <Level>1</Level>
   </HighScoreData>

   <HighScoreData>
      <PlanerName>Player 2</PlayerName>
      <Score>100</Score>
      <Level>1</Level>
   </HighScoreData>

...
</xml>
```